# xts - last obervation in a period

Tags: r, xts

I know that this must be an easy task but I got stucked and cannot move forward.

I have the following xts:

```
                     timestamp    id         type  price     size          api   
2014-05-02 00:02:07 "1398981727" "36833484" "BID" "449.247" "9.00000e-02" "TRUE"
2014-05-02 00:02:07 "1398981727" "36833485" "BID" "449.248" "5.42886e-02" "TRUE"
2014-05-02 00:03:04 "1398981784" "36833488" "BID" "449.246" "4.66000e+00" "TRUE"
2014-05-02 00:03:12 "1398981792" "36833489" "BID" "449.246" "5.90000e-01" "TRUE"
2014-05-02 00:03:12 "1398981792" "36833490" "BID" "449.246" "4.00000e-02" "TRUE"
2014-05-02 00:03:14 "1398981794" "36833491" "BID" "449.246" "2.00000e-02" "TRUE"
2014-05-02 00:03:23 "1398981803" "36833498" "BID" "449.240" "1.00000e-02" "TRUE"
2014-05-02 00:04:55 "1398981895" "36833504" "BID" "448.790" "9.89321e-02" "TRUE"
2014-05-02 00:04:55 "1398981895" "36833505" "BID" "449.108" "1.75000e+00" "TRUE"
2014-05-02 00:04:55 "1398981895" "36833506" "BID" "449.110" "5.21441e-01" "TRUE"
2014-05-02 00:05:26 "1398981926" "36833508" "ASK" "447.000" "5.16985e-01" "TRUE"
2014-05-02 00:05:26 "1398981926" "36833509" "ASK" "446.473" "1.20000e-02" "TRUE"
2014-05-02 00:05:26 "1398981926" "36833510" "ASK" "446.205" "1.04000e-02" "TRUE"
```

from which I want to build another xts containing last observation in every second for a given type of order (BID or ASK, column type).

For instance for ASK orders, I want to build xts like this:

```
2014-05-02 00:02:07      NA
2014-05-02 00:03:04      NA
2014-05-02 00:03:12      NA
2014-05-02 00:03:14      NA
2014-05-02 00:03:23      NA
2014-05-02 00:04:55      NA
2014-05-02 00:05:26 446.205
```

New xts has to contain same index as the old one. Timestamps with no ASK orders should be NA.

I tried this

```
xts(period.apply(temp, INDEX = endpoints(temp, on = "secs", k = 1), FUN = function(x) tail(as.numeric(x$price[x$type == "ASK"]), 1)))
```

where temp = the xts input above. But it always ands up with following error:

```
Error in coredata.xts(x) : currently unsupported data type.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `period.apply` is meant to aggregate objects, but you're removing rows. That means the result of the first 6 function evaluates are `numeric(0)`, which aren't a valid value for an observation.

If there are no observations, you need to return `NA`. That means you need to modify your function a bit to return `NA` if there are no ask observations.

```
f <- function(x) {
  y <- tail(as.numeric(x$price[x$type == "ASK"]), 1)
  if(!length(y)) NA else y
}
period.apply(temp, endpoints(temp, "secs"), f)
```

There's probably a better way to accomplish your objective, but you would need to provide more details on what you're ultimately trying to do.